# Show obsolete/deprecated class usages in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

### Context

We had quite a big memory leak in a WPF application we are developping that was caused by the use of [`DropShadowBitmapEffect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadowbitmapeffect.aspx) in a resource library.

The drop shadow was used by some `UserControl` and by all our menus to cast a shadow over the actual content of the window, as such:

```
<DropShadowBitmapEffect x:Key="PopupDropShadow" ShadowDepth="1.5" Softness="0.15" />
...
<Rectangle BitmapEffect="{StaticResource PopupDropShadow}" ... />
```

I had to profile the application for many hours before I actually found the cause of the problem. The `DropShadowBitmapEffect` class is unmanaged and prevents objects from being GC'd. Also, you'll note that the `DropShadowBitmapEffect` class ***is marked as Obsolete***, and that there is an updated class named [`DropShadowEffect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect.aspx) that fixes the memory leak (and [is also hardware accelerated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/05/15/what-s-new-for-performance-in-wpf-in-net-3-5-sp1.aspx) thus improves render performance a whole lot). Here is the actual fix:

```
<DropShadowEffect x:Key="PopupDropShadow" ShadowDepth="1.5" />
...    
<Rectangle Effect="{StaticResource PopupDropShadow}" ... />
```

### Question

**Is it possible to have the deprecated/obsolete class usages throw warnings on compile when used in XAML in Visual Studio 2010?**

Comment: One issue is the classes themselves are not marked as `Obsolete`, only a few scattered methods on the `BitmapEffect` base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it for XAML but [Gendarme](https://github.com/spouliot/gendarme) has [a rule that checks for the use of obsolete code](https://github.com/spouliot/gendarme/wiki/Gendarme.Rules.Maintainability.RemoveDependenceOnObsoleteCodeRule%282.10%29).

Comment: The types themselves are not marked with `ObsoleteAttribute` on a smattering of methods on them.

Comment: Gendarme doesn't just check types it checks for the Obsolete attribute so that would be OK.

Comment: If these are used in XAML and those methods are called by internal framework code, where would Gendarme warn about Obsolete usage?

Comment: @sixlettervariables, You are correct, that would be 'impossible' to catch. However, the question at the of the OP is broader than that.

Comment: Thanks for the input Erno. I'll have a look at Gendarme.
I think it should be quite easy to hook-it up to our continuous integration process - we are using CCNet and there is a plugin for Gendarme.

Comment: I think there is a way in Visual C++ to warn when using deprecated/obsolete class within in the solution (within the IDE)... It's a shame there is no way to do that in VS2010 though??

Comment: Gendarme doesn't work with xaml - I tested it on our project. Resharper appears to work on properties but not classes. This is frustrating.